# Method invocation with out parameter and no additional variable?

Tags: c#, parameter-passing, out

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Null out parameters in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414469/null-out-parameters-in-c)

In some cases while calling a certain method I am not interested in all values in the method signature. Then I use either default or null values for them.

But in case of `out` or `ref` references in method signature I always have to define a dummy variable that I pass to this method:

```
    public static bool IsNumber(this Token token)
    {
        int tmp = 0;
        return Int32.TryParse(token.Data,out tmp);
    }
```

So, my question is whether I can somehow eliminate this varibale (it is assigned by never read!) and still correctly call the method requiring an `out` parameter?

Comment: That's how `out` parameters work. There has to be a variable for the function to write to.